# Passport dashboard without a rendering engine

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using passport's local strategy to authenticate the user. After a successfull login every tutorial is using a rendering engine and here's the question. How can I render a dashboard (display username) without one?

```js
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/auth/user", //redirection to the dashboard
    failureRedirect: "/login?error=true"
}));

router.get("/user", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ user: req.user }); //how do i display an html FILE with it?
})
```

Comment: Just `res.send("<!DOCTYPE html><html>........</html>")`?

Comment: I wanted to send it in a FILE as I specified in the comment

Comment: What do you mean by "send it in a FILE"? You have a `.html` file and you wish to replace the user's information inside that file, or what? `fs.readFile` and `res.send()` or `res.sendFile()`?

Comment: I just want the page (if that's possible) to be sent with some json containing the user's info. Is that possible? So like res.sendfile() and the res.json()? But I don't know how would I handle the json data. So is there a possibility to do so? Otherwise can I just fs.readfile and then just replace every {{user.name}} with the users name, but that's just like the render engines

Comment: Well, you could send the user data as a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) or in a response header? If the JSON is used programmatically in the client side over JS, those will be alright. If you want to manipulate the HTML to for example replace a user's name on the page, just use a render engine or string replace, or use client-side JavaScript to read the cookie and manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Is there a reason for not wanting to use a rendering engine or string replace? What exactly will the JSON be used for? Who will use it and how?

Comment: It's too much work for that to work. I just wanted a plain HTML but I guess I'll just use ejs for this. I thought it would be a lot easier. Thank's for all of the ideas though